# MySQLWorkbench :Cannot connect MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench

When i try to connect to the MySQL server i am incurring following error messages

Kindly let me know what is the problem with my MySQL server

```
dev@dev-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:~$ ifconfig|grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet addr:192.168.170.50  Bcast:192.168.170.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
dev@dev-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:~$ mysql -ubeer -pbeer -h192.168.170.50
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.170.50' (111)
dev@dev-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:~$ mysql -ubeer -pbeer -h127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
dev@dev-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:~$ mysql -ubeer -pbeer -hlocalhost
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This is my.cnf file should i make some changes in my.cnf inorder to connect to MySQL server ?

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: `mysql -ubeer -pbeer `...because `beer` :v .....are you sure your service is running.... type: `service mysql status` and post the output...also post your OS name and version(type `cat /etc/issue`)

Comment: Following is the output from MySQL status  : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) and this is my OS : Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l

Comment: And if you type: `service mysql start`..then check the status

Comment: Following is the output : service mysql start
start: Unknown job: mysql

Comment: Follow this guide: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04   ...you can also check this Q&A: http://serverfault.com/questions/599686/xubuntu-desktop-14-04-service-mysql-start-unknown-job

Comment: I am always getting an error :                                                                                                            │  
 │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened   
 │ because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.  │  
 │                                                                                                           │  
 │ You should check the account's password after the package installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a fresh installation? If so, please check if mysql-server installed instead of mysql-client

```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Also, try changing this line in your my.cnf to:

```
   bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

After that

```
   sudo service mysql restart
```

**ANOTHER POSSIBILITY:**

You may want to try finding the socket like this:

```
   sudo find / -type s
```

Once found, you can create a symlink to a temporary folder like this:

```
   sudo ln -s /path-to-socket/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

After  all this, you may want to reinstall MySQL Server and installing it again.

Comment: Yes,its first installation, I will check this and will let you know immediately

Comment: Aborting downgrade from (at least) 5.6 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I encourage you to reinstall the server like this:

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server --purge`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: This is what i get after i start mysql  : sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

Comment: please, show your log: `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: Following is the message i am getting after re installation : dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

 
 
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server

Comment: Following is the message :  tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
160812 20:28:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
160812 20:28:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160812 20:28:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160812 20:28:16 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160812 20:28:16 [ERROR] Aborting

160812 20:28:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server --purge` will remove all your dependencies. If that doesn't work, `sudo apt-get -f install` will try fix dependency errors, then `sudo dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: I am getting this error again : dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 no package named `mysql-server-5.5' is installed, cannot configure
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5

Comment: try this to see what happens `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: I am getting same error : start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean`

Comment: I am still getting an error which says  │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened │ because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server. │ │ │ │ You should check the account's password after the package installation

Comment: run again all those lines in terminal, and after that, run this `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`. After that, you should be able to reinstall mysql server again with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-workbench`

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i have resolved this issue